# dplyr lazy query mutate column using str_extract

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr, dbplyr

I try to query a table `table_a`, and I like to mutate a column `substr_col` based on an existing column `col` with `stringr::str_extract` while it is in a lazy query state. I encountered an error message complaining `col` does not exist.

> object 'col' not found

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
dplyr::tbl(conn, table_a) %>%
dplyr::mutate(substring_col = stringr::str_extract(col, "^[A-Z]-\\d{3}")) %>%
dplyr::collect()
```

But this code works when I collect the data first and then call `stringr::str_extract`

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(...)
dplyr::tbl(conn, table_a) %>%
dplyr::collect() %>%
dplyr::mutate(substring_col = stringr::str_extract(col, "^[A-Z]-\\d{3}"))
```

I like to use the `substring_col` as a filter condition while the query is lazy, how should I do that?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `plyr::mutate` and not `dplyr::mutate`? I think think `plyr` works with lazy tables.

Comment: To do a lazy query you'd want `dplyr::mutate`. But even then, I don't think `str_extract` will be translated to SQL, because it's not in the list of dbplyr's [known functions](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html)

Comment: @MrFlick It was a typo (now changed plyr:: to dplyr::).

Answer (score 2):

As @IceCreanToucan states, `str_extract` is not on dbplyr's list of translations. Hence it will not be able to execute this code on the database. (I assume you are using dbplyr as it is the main package for having dplyr commands translated into SQL).

We can test this as follows:

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data(starwars)

# pick your simulated connection type (there are many options, not just what I have shown here)
remote_df = tbl_lazy(starwars, con = simulate_mssql())
remote_df = tbl_lazy(starwars, con = simulate_mysql())
remote_df = tbl_lazy(starwars, con = simulate_postgres())

remote_df %>%
  mutate(substring_col = str_extract(name, "Luke")) %>%
  show_query()
```

`show_query()` should return the SQL that our mutate has been translated into. But instead I receive a clear message: "Error: str_extract() is not available in this SQL variant". This makes it clear translation is not defined.

However, there is a translation defined for `grep` and `grepl` (etc.) so the following should work:

```r
remote_df %>%
  mutate(substring_col = grepl("Luke", name)) %>%
  show_query()
```

But it will return you slightly different output.